# How to execute i3 commands from systemctl?

Tags: linux, bash, inotify, systemctl, i3

I am trying to run an `i3` command using `inotify`. In my case, `inotify` is started using `systemctl`.

#### systemctl script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Inode event watcher

[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/services/inotify/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

#### /usr/local/services/inotify/start.sh:

```sh
I3_CURRENT_WORKSPACE='/etc/i3/script/swiping-workspace/current'
I3_UPDATE_WORKSPACE="/etc/i3/script/swiping-workspace/update.sh"
inotify $I3_WORKSPACE_TRIGGER $I3_WORKSPACE_UPDATE &
```

Note: my goal here is to execute `update.sh` when the `current` file is changed on disk.

#### /etc/i3/script/swiping-workspace/update.sh:

```sh
sudo -u $user i3 workspace $(cat $I3_CURRENT_WORKSPACE)
```

where `$user` is the user in which i3 has been installed. I am running this command as root. I also tried these switches, no avail: `SCREEN=':0' -E -H`

#### The issue:

When an `inotify` event is triggered, an error occurs. Here is the log message I get (using `journalctl`):

```
<date> start.sh[1427]: /etc/i3/script/swiping-workspace/ MODIFY current
<date> sudo[6698]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=$user ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/i3 workspace "6"
<date> sudo[6698]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user $user by (uid=0)
<date> start.sh[1427]: <date> - Additional arguments passed. Sending them as a command to i3.
<date> start.sh[1427]: <date> - ERROR: Could not get i3 IPC socket path
<date> sudo[6698]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user $user
```

I don't understand why `i3` fails to receive the command `systemctl` sends it.

The whole setup actually works if I start the `inotify` command myself (in a unique terminal) instead of using systemctl.

Anybody having a clue?

Comment: 1. Run the script as your own user
2. Ensure you set the DISPLAY variable correctly

Comment: See edited post. I tried to set `$SCREEN` with sudo's `-E` switch, and also I tried the `-H` switch, no avail.

Comment: The correct variable is `DISPLAY`, not `$SCREEN`. You may also need `XAUTHORITY`. Bear in mind that sudo may have policies disallowing non-whitelisted environment variables.

Comment: Your script also still has `User=root` in the service file, and is using the `i3` command when it should use the `i3-msg` command.